# Airflow operational metrics dashboard

Tags: airflow

We have airflow open source and we need to have some sort of dashboard with the following information:

1. Number of failed Dags in the past month
2. Number of DAGS that had config json value that was re-run

I understand that I can read the data from airflow DB, run queries and add that to Powerbi dashboard. I was wondering if Airflow has an alternate solution for my requirements

Answer (score 0):

Starting Airflow 2.7.0 there is a new dashboard called Cluster Activity that shows various of live and historical metrics over the cluster.

> Number of failed Dags in the past month

Can be seen in the below image (you can set date rage as you see fit)

[image]

> Number of DAGS that had config json value that was re-run

This is not available in the dashboard and very specific request thus chances are it will not be added in future releases. I suggest to write a custom dashboard for it as you suggested.

Noting: By the time of writing this answer Airflow 2.7.0 is not yet released ([RC1 is available](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/2.7.0rc1/)), release is expected in few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin: https://github.com/airflow-plugins/airflow-exporter 
Then create a dashboard in Grafana.

According to point 2, I think it can be added to the plugin source code